# .Net Core POST model sent by Angular 8 receives default values

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

from Angular 8 / TS I have no problem sending basic types and objects with basic types. But with more complex models I am only receiving default values, and I don't know if I am missing something.

Here you got the POST call from TS and the models, from Angular and C#

I am wondering if this sort of bindings, arrays of models, must be done manually or I am doing something wrong.

[image: parameters]

[image]

**TS**

```
return this.http.post<void>(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'api/WorkFlow/AddWorkflow', workflowDTO);



export class WorkflowDTO {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    stepItemsToDelete: Array<Step>;
    stepItemsToAdd: Array<Step>;
    stepOrder: Array<StepOrder>;
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = '';
        this.description = '';
        this.stepItemsToAdd = [];
        this.stepItemsToDelete = [];
        this.stepOrder = [];
    }
}
export class StepOrder {
    id: number;
    order: number;
}
export class Step {
    id: number;
    workflowId: number;
    stepTypeId: number;
    text: string;
    path: string;
    stepOrder: number;
    stepName: string;
    imageFile:  string;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public int AddWorkflow(WorkflowDTO workflowDTO)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) //it is always true
    {
        return 0;
    }
        return 1;
}

public class WorkflowDTO
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<Step> stepItemsToDelete { get; set; }
        public List<Step> stepItemsToAdd { get; set; }
        public List<StepOrder> stepOrder { get; set; }
    }
    public class Step
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int workflowId { get; set; }
        public int stepTypeId { get; set; }
        public int stepOrder { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string stepName { get; set; }
        public string imageFile { get; set; }
    }
    public class StepOrder
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the FromBody model binding attribute to your controller method:

public int AddWorkflow([FromBody] WorkflowDTO workflowDTO)

Also, it may not be able to map your TS class because of your property types. I’ve never tried typing my arrays like that, but it could cause a problem. I know for sure the syntax below works.

stepItemsToDelete: Step[];

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, change Array to [] is TS did not work. Also, I have tried removing List from backend and use [] instead with no luck.

[fromBody] is something I add and remove sometimes to test it, in case it has effect.

From POST, I also try to send workflowDTO and {workflowDTO} sometimes randomly, trying to find the solution.

I add a screenshot to the question, which displays the values my backend receives.

ModelState object does not provide useful information, because it is valid

Comment: What is the response you get? Because you mentioned that your modelState is valid, your response has a status code of 200 and returns 1 every time. Is that correct? Have you tried console logging the body of the request in the Angular code? Just to make sure the API is getting the data we think it’s getting.

Comment: Yes, everything is right and I receive 1. :S

I add a console log screenshot.